# Stack image and text left to right on same row

Tags: html, css

Hi having some issues here trying to stack image and text on the same line left to right.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 30px;">
    <span style="float: left;">
        <img class="tglbtn" src="img/toggle_tab_l.png" data-swap='img/toggle_tab_r.png' height="60%" width="60%">
    </span>
    <p style="float: right; font-size: 20px; color: #92d6f8; overflow: hidden; text-align: left">
        Remember User ID?
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code
http://jsfiddle.net/21Ltsbeb/
Improved
http://jsfiddle.net/21Ltsbeb/1/

I'm not seeing the issue? Though, you might be better off using display:inline-block with matching html elements. Inline as in Have these elements **in** the same **line**

```css
.tglbtn {width:60%;height:60%;}
span {display:inline-block;}
p {font-size:20px;color:#92d6f8;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
        <img class="tglbtn" src="http://www.placehold.it/66x66">
    </span>
    <span>
    Remember User ID?
    </span>
</div>
```

### Edit

A few things I should note that you need to address as a beginner.

- Don't use inline css
- Don't use pixels (rem,em,or %)
- Avoiding using position absolute
- Don't use floats
- Remember that good web applications have great continuity in their structure.

Until you get the hang of CSS, I might recommend Foundation's CSS or Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: I was happy until i saw *Avoiding using position absolute* and I am at a lose as to why anyone would recommend ***Bootstrap*** of all things!

Comment: Bootstrap is made by professionals. As a professional, I recognize this and ignore the hipster trend of bashing bootstrap for being mainstream and over-used. Good structure is good structure, only individuals well-practiced in front-end design should stray from pre-established designs. Position absolute is very rarely used for it's original purpose, and it is too often a crutch for propping up bad structuring.

Answer (score 0):

This could be cleaned up *a lot* for you, and also simplifying your css/removing a lot of the inline styling:

```css
.mind{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
.tglbtn{
  height:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="tglbtn" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" data-swap='img/toggle_tab_r.png' />
  <div class="mind">Remember User ID?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the paragraphs top margin to 0

```
margin-top:0;
```

It's being set by the browser default otherwise (I see the mis-alignment in chrome).

See this fixed [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nwpv93L8/)